# Is this a bug in NSolve in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, numerical-methods, polynomial-math

One would expect and hope that if you ask `Mathematica` to find the roots of a polynomial, it should give the same (approximate) answers whether you do this symbolically, then find numerical approximations to these exact answers, or whether you do it numerically. Here's an example which (in `Mathematica 7`, running on OS X) where this fails badly:

```
poly = -112 + 1/q^28 + 1/q^26 - 1/q^24 - 6/q^22 - 14/q^20 - 25/q^18 -
  38/q^16 - 52/q^14 - 67/q^12 - 81/q^10 - 93/q^8 - 102/q^6 - 108/
  q^4 - 111/q^2 - 111 q^2 - 108 q^4 - 102 q^6 - 93 q^8 - 81 q^10 -
  67 q^12 - 52 q^14 - 38 q^16 - 25 q^18 - 14 q^20 - 6 q^22 - q^24 +
  q^26 + q^28;

Total[q^4 /. NSolve[poly == 0, q]] - Total[q^4 /. N[Solve[poly == 0, q]]]
```

(Note: this is actually a Laurent polynomial, and if you multiply through by a large power of `q` the problem goes away.)

The last line here is just a demonstration that the solutions found are very different; in fact it's the quantity we were trying to compute in the problem we were working on.

If you look closely at the output of `NSolve[poly == 0, q]` and of `N[Solve[poly == 0, q]`, you'll see that NSolve only gives `54` roots instead of the expected `56`. It's not that it just missed a repeated root or anything; it's missing the two largest roots in magnitude (approximately `+/- 1.59`)

> Is this a bug in Mathematica? Does anyone have an explanation for why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately your expectations are unfounded.

As you say, `Solve[]` gives an exact solution and `N[]` introduces a small error, but only once, when you evaluate it. `NSolve[]` on the other hand uses numerical approximations from the get go and thus significant rounding error can accumulate.

You are also limited by the default precision for the calculation and this can lead to complete failure of the numerical method, e.g., missing roots (see [Wilkinson's polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial)). You can counteract this by telling `NSolve[]` to use greater precision like so:

```
In[1]  := Total[q^4 /. NSolve[poly == 0, q, WorkingPrecision -> 50]] - 
          Total[q^4 /. N[Solve[poly == 0, q]]]
Out[1] := 0. - 3.66374*10^-15 I
```

When using numerical methods it is always important to keep the errors in mind. Since this is true for for a large variety of [numerical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) problems from solving long polynomials to diagonalizing large matrices to integration of weird functions etc. etc. there is no one correct approach, and Mathematica needs to be told to, e.g., raise the WorkingPrecision, or to apply a different numerical technique.

Comment: Two additional notes: 1.) `NSolve[]` supports an abbreviated syntax: `NSolve[poly, var, prec]` 2.) In using `NSolve[]` for finding polynomial roots, there is no "different numerical technique"; all it knows is Jenkins-Traub (in essence, a fancy Rayleigh quotient iteration); one can however construct the Frobenius companion matrix and use `Eigenvalues[]`.

Comment: Maybe this is new in v8, but NSolve certainly accepts the Method option http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSolve.html. And in any case I was talking about numerical methods in general.